# javascript accessing subframe url from another subframe (just confirming for umpteenth time that may not be possible)

Tags: javascript, url, frames

Have frame setup with top, main, and switchboard.  I want to get address of any page that's in main to populate text box in switchboard on a button click.  I've tried everything I could find, including stack's answers, but no dice, unless I'm doing something wrong (strong possibility of that).  So, at this point just looking for confirmation that it can't be done.

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem if all are on same domain, protocol and port. Are you aware that frames are deprecated? Hard to imagine why anyone would use them in this day and age. Provide more details and code attempts as well as relevant html and frameset structure

Comment: What you are describing doesn't sound like it should be a problem, but without any code showing your attempts, it's not obvious what you are doing or not doing.